# date format in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello every one i have a problem with mysql dbms i never had a date storage in this format yyyy-mm-dd i always have it in this format dd-mm-yyyy i used this methode to change the date format while inserting data but it does not work

```
function dateConvert($dateInser) {
 $dateTime = new DateTime($dateInser);
 $dateFormate=date_format ( $dateTime, 'Y-m-d' );
  return $dateFormate;
}
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: In database the format of the date time will be always same and will not change.

Comment: yes sir but the user input should be like this dd-mm-yyyy and i have to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd because of mysql what do you suggest ?

Comment: this function works perfectly

Comment: yeah but the values @ phpmyadmin looks 0000-00-00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTime constructor also expects specific formats, and I doubt dd-mm-yyyy is one of them. First parse your dd-mm-yyyy date to transform it into a DateTime object, and then format this DateTime object using the yyyy-mm-dd format :

```
$dateTime = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $dateInser);
$dateFormate = date_format($dateTime, 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: it does not work ! Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in ..

Comment: This probably means that FALSE is returned from the date_create_from_format call, which means $dateInser doesn't contain a valid 'd-m-Y' date.

Comment: it's solved i used this mysql function STR_TO_DATE('$dateInser', '%m-%d-%Y')